# Approving "One" in a one-to-many DB relationship only when ALL "Many"s are approved

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2010, one-to-many

I've tried looking for this I promise, but its kind of a hard question to search for...

I have a database with two tables linked in a one-to-many relationship where each "one" is an invoice header linked to "many" invoice lines.

I am designing a tool that will match each invoice line to a purchase order and I want to be able to mark an invoice header as "matched" only when all lines have been matched.

Does anyone know how to write this update query?

Comment: Can you give us some sample data?

Comment: Are you saying you need to see if there are any un-matched invoice lines? Seems like it would be easy

Comment: I need to be able to not just see that there are unmatched lines I need to be able to update the invoice record to "matched" only when all invoice lines are marked as "matched".

Comment: I can't share sample data due to its sensitive nature but in the most simplistic terms think of two tables, one for invoices that contains an invoice number/ID and a match flag field, the other for lines that links via the invoice number/ID, had line numbers also and a match flag field. If all 20 lines of an invoice are ticked for match I want to be able to update the invoice table to say that invoice is matched, if only 19 out of 20 lines are matched I do not want the invoice marked as matched....

Comment: Sample data isn't real data, you can make it up. It only must match the **structure** of the real data. Use http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to post it (including desired result). This is so much more useful than a textual description.

Answer (score 0):

The relational operator you seek is known formally as `division` and colloquially as "the suppliers who supply all parts". For various reasons, a `division` operator has not appeared in any SQL product I know of, Access included. Instead, you need to use other operators in combination to do the same. See [Divided we stand: the SQL of relational division by Joe Celko](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).

Answer (score 0):

An approach available to users of Access 2010 and later is to use event-driven data macros in the child table to maintain the status flag in the parent table. For example, with a parent table

```
[InvHeader]

InvID  AllMatched
-----  ----------
    1          No
```

and a child table

```
[InvItem]

ItemID  InvID  Matched
------  -----  -------
     1      1      Yes
     2      1       No
```

the following After Update data macro will automatically update the corresponding row in [InvHeader] after a child row has been changed in [InvItem]

[image: AfterUpdate.png]

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<DataMacros xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/accessservices/2009/11/application">
    <DataMacro Event="AfterUpdate">
        <Statements>
            <Action Collapsed="true" Name="SetLocalVar">
                <Argument Name="Name">newAllMatched</Argument>
                <Argument Name="Value">True</Argument>
            </Action>
            <ForEachRecord>
                <Data Alias="i">
                    <Reference>InvItem</Reference>
                    <WhereCondition>[i].[InvID]=[InvItem].[InvID]</WhereCondition>
                </Data>
                <Statements>
                    <ConditionalBlock>
                        <If>
                            <Condition>Not [i].[Matched]</Condition>
                            <Statements>
                                <Action Collapsed="true" Name="SetLocalVar">
                                    <Argument Name="Name">newAllMatched</Argument>
                                    <Argument Name="Value">False</Argument>
                                </Action>
                                <Action Name="ExitForEachRecord"/>
                            </Statements>
                        </If>
                    </ConditionalBlock>
                </Statements>
            </ForEachRecord>
            <LookUpRecord>
                <Data Alias="hdr">
                    <Reference>InvHeader</Reference>
                    <WhereCondition>[hdr].[InvID]=[InvItem].[InvID]</WhereCondition>
                </Data>
                <Statements>
                    <ConditionalBlock>
                        <If>
                            <Condition>[hdr].[AllMatched]&lt;&gt;[newAllMatched]</Condition>
                            <Statements>
                                <EditRecord>
                                    <Data Alias="hdr"/>
                                    <Statements>
                                        <Action Collapsed="true" Name="SetField">
                                            <Argument Name="Field">AllMatched</Argument>
                                            <Argument Name="Value">[newAllMatched]</Argument>
                                        </Action>
                                    </Statements>
                                </EditRecord>
                            </Statements>
                        </If>
                    </ConditionalBlock>
                </Statements>
            </LookUpRecord>
        </Statements>
    </DataMacro>
</DataMacros>
```

Note that this is an example for updates only. For completeness, one would normally put the above code in a named data macro and call it from After Insert, After Update, and After Delete.